# How to batch demux sound from videos to mp3 or aac

Tags: audio, video, batch-processing, converter

I have more then 1000 videos that i want to use for radio over Shoutcast.

Recommend a software to batch demux audio from video files to mp3 or aac. Video are original formats for TV broadcasting so the quality of the sound is excellent.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=ffmpeg+demux+example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 1):

As leftaroundabout said, use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) (or avconv - the one is forked off the other).
It is command line based, which makes it useful for batch operations.
On my Linux box the batch command would be something similar to:

```
for FILE in *.mp4
do ffmpeg -i $FILE $FILE.mp3
done
```

Use the *-c:a copy* option if you just want to strip away video and use the audio codec as-is.

I don't know how the loop would look in Windows.

I you don't want to use the command line, just google for some utility. There are probably hundreds.

Comment: Yep, there are to many, all doing the same thing, all are described as best (ofcourse), thats why i ask for recommendation from community here. It can be OSX or Windows. I am not good with command line altough i have tried ffmpeg, but would need something with UI so i can give it to others to work with.

Comment: Ok, well, I don't have any experience to recommend one. Sorry!